# How to access "container" methods from "has-a" (contained) class

Tags: java, composition

I am trying to use composition to break up functionality, but am not sure how to refer back to the "encapsulating" class (not sure what a level up is called in composition).  Here is a contrived example where the Body can see Leg methods, but the Leg cannot see Body methods.  Do I have to change an access modifier or instantiate differently?  Thanks in advance.

```
public class Body {

    private Leg leg;

    public Body() {
        leg = new Leg();
    }

    public void takeStep() {
        leg.move();
    }

    public Boolean isStanding() {
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Body body = new Body();
        body.takeStep();
    }
}
```

``

```
public class Leg {

    public void move() {
        if(body.isStanding()) // PROBLEM:  no access to body
            ; // <extend details>
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you can also try like      public void takeStep() {
     if(isStanding())
      leg.move();
    }

Comment: `body` is a **local** variable of `main` method.  It can't be visible outside the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the container methods by passing its reference when instantiating the contained class. So, you would declare your `Leg` class as

```
public class Leg {

    Body parent;

    public Leg(Body parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void move() {
        if(parent.isStanding()) // PROBLEM:  no access to body
            ; // <extend details>
    }

}
```

You would instantiate the `Leg` within `Body` as

```
public Body() {
    leg = new Leg(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try like below by passing the value as argument

```
public class Body {

    private Leg leg;

    public Body() {
        leg = new Leg();
    }

    public void takeStep() {
        leg.move(isStanding());
    }

    public Boolean isStanding() {
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Body body = new Body();
        body.takeStep();
    }
}
class Leg{
    public void move( boolean isStanding){
        if(isStanding){
            // your code
        }
    }
}
```